# Is there any difference between "git push -d remote branch" and "git push remote :branch"

Tags: git

There are two ways to delete a remote branch in Git:

```sh
git push -d remote branch
git push remote :branch
```

I wonder if there's any difference. Per my understanding, the first command explicitly tells Git to delete a branch (`-d` is short for `--delete`), and the second command is a specific form of `push remote [[+]ref:]ref`, but that doesn't explain the differences, if present.

Comment: The difference is entirely which command you type in. To the server receiving the request, there is no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same. It's explained in [git-push Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--d).

> -d
>
> --delete
>
> All listed refs are deleted from the remote repository. This is the
> same as prefixing all refs with a colon.